# C# Web parsing web service response

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I need to create an application that gets the stock value of a corporation using web services. I currently have a reference to the web service but I do not know how to parse the XML string I get. How do I select just the stock value?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StockRefrence.StockQuote callWeb = new StockRefrence.StockQuote();
    string stock = callWeb.GetQuote("CSCO");
    Label1.Text = stock;
}
```

The web service I'm using http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=9&CATID=2

Comment: There is a gigantic amount of information regarding XML parsing in .NET. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: provide a sample of the xml and the part of the xml you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use XPath:

[.Net XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)